# Django Celery, not executing scheduled tasks

Tags: python, django, celery, periodic-task

I'm developing a Django application to track crypto assets, what Im looking to do is, to take a snapshot of the user total value every 5 Days (X time).

What i did for now:

core/celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')

app = Celery('core')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')


app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'print': {
        'task': 'app.tasks.test',
        'schedule': 15
    },
}
app.conf.timezone = 'UTC'

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

core/settings.py:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Copyright (c) 2019 - present AppSeed.us
"""


import os
from decouple import config
from unipath import Path
import dj_database_url
import django


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).parent
CORE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY', default='S#perS3crEt_1122')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=True, cast=bool)

# load production server from .env
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'e6b5f240dedb.ngrok.io',
                 config('SERVER', default='127.0.0.1')]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [



    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django_celery_beat',



    'chartjs',
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.google",


    'app'
]
SITE_ID = 2
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"   # Route defined in app/urls.py
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/login"  # Route defined in app/urls.py
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(
    CORE_DIR, "core/templates")  # ROOT dir for templates


SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'

# Celery Configuration Options
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "Europe/Sofia"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Cron jobs


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

#############################################################
# SRC: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'core/static'),
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)
#############################################################
#############################################################
```

app/tasks.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def test():
    print("Message for me and for you")
```

and right after, when i execute

```
celery -A core worker -l info
```

i get error "celery: command not found"

Note: I did python manage.py migrate, and Im able to see new table in admin page.
When i run the project, no error is showing but the task is not executing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't installed Django Celery on your server, run

```
pip install django-celery
```

then restart everything again

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time and answer. I installed that, and still, celery: command not found